# Implementing drag and drop for TreeView nodes in Avalonia

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, avaloniaui

How to implement drag and drop behavior in TreeView control? An example would be a file explorer where user can move file from one folder to another by dragging.

I have the following code in my XAML:

```
<TreeView Items="{Binding RootFiles}">
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
     </TreeDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

[image: file explorer]

How do I make the nodes draggable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have a proper drag-n-drop support yet, unfortunately, so you have to implement it manually.

I'll describe how I did something similar with adaptations for your case.

You can handle mouse events on TreeView control level. When `MouseDown` fires, you need to check `PointerOverElement` property to detect if mouse is currently inside one of the nodes of the tree (use Parent property to traverse the tree or simply check DataContext), if it is, you need to save said node somewhere.
When `MouseMove` event fires when one of mouse buttons is pressed, you need to capture mouse and from this point your code is in "drag" state. You can change TreeView's `Cursor` property to provide some feedback to the user
When `MouseUp` is triggered, you need to detect the position of the cursor relatively to other nodes and make changes in the model backing TreeView accordingly.

Comment: `MouseMove` event you mean `PointerMoved`? It isn't triggered, when mouse button is pressed

Comment: Is this answer still current 6 years later?